# drawLine vs scaled 1px bitmap line - best practice? (Android)

Tags: android, bitmap

Just a quick question,

When displaying a series of moving vertical lines, would it be better to use the canvas 'drawLine' command or scale a 1px bitmap to the required size? Example:

```
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStrokeWidth(8f);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
canvas.drawLine(xPos, yPos1, xPos, yPos2, paint);
```

or

```
CCSprite line = CCSprite.sprite("red_px.png");
line.setScaleX(lineWidthScale);
line.setScaleY(heightScale);
line.setPosition(xPos, yPos1);
```

I've tried done both and the outcome is identical but I'm wonder what is considered best practice.

Also, I guess there's a third option of rendering the canvas to bitmp.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(x, y, Config.ARGB_8888); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawLine(xPos, yPos1, xPos, yPos2, paint);
CCSprite line = CCSprite.sprite(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap ), "line");
```

Comment: I'd always recommend drawLine, easier to let the gpu do the drawing and use less hardcoded image files/bitmaps

Comment: @xBroak Thanks, I'm stick with the drawLine method.